# Tensorflow: Too many dimensions

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to create a TensorFlow (2.0) variable like this:

```
c_init = tf.zeros_initializer()
c = tf.Variable(initial_value=c_init(shape=shape, dtype="float32"), trainable=True)
```

the shape variable is this:

```
shape=(49, 52, 26, 49, 6, 3, 31, 11, 24, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

I'm getting this error message:

> InvalidArgumentError: Too many dimensions [Op:Fill] name: zeros/

I did not know there is a limit in the number of dimensions. I did not see anything in TensorFlow documentation about it. Is there any way to get around this limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The max number of dimensions is 254
2. Get around this limitation?

If you don't mind, I do have to ask you a question:
Are you sure you have that many dimensions in your problem? I have seen people mistakenly using size of dimension as number of dimensions. Are you sure you have so many dimensions with size 1?

Let's not forget that there is no need to represent anything as tensors. We could solve any problem without using a multi-dimensional data type (tensor). The reason why this type of representation is used is because it allows certain linear algebra operations to be applied and they are much fast when compared to regular loops in a more traditional code.

So, yes, you can get around this limitation but you will need to so some "soul search" and figure out what kind of math operations you are planning to apply to this humongous tensor.

Comment: Thank you! I needed to create a tensor with these dimensions to use reduce_mean() or reduce_sum() along several dimensions. I could flatten the variable, but then I need to figure out how to do the reduce operations. BTW, the dimensions of size 1 are accidental. I do have situations, when all dimensions are non-trivial.

Comment: Welcome ! I don't know any framework that would handle such a large number of dimensions. As you mentioned, you could flatten your data to a "2D matrix" and keep track of column indexes for each dimension. Finally a "reduce_sum" operation could be done on a "column slice". It would be painful and probably slow but could work.